# Sign up a new user but return http error if username or email already exists

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, response

I'm trying to learn spring but I have a hard time understanding how to use it.

I currently have a react frontend, a sign up page, that accepts username, password and an email and on submit it creates a post request on route /signup (using fetch).

On the backend side, I have a user model class and a controller that has a method on this route that accepts users and saves them on a **PostGreSQL** database.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SignUpController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepo repo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void signUp(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        repo.save(user);
        System.out.println("NEW USER SUBMISSION!!!");
    }
}
```

So, now I want 2 things:

1. The username is the table's id. However, if the username or the email is already inside the table, i want to prevent the submission. Not only that, i want to return an http error respose (i guess a 403) with the specific message so that i can update the frontend to give a feedback to the user. So, it would be a different message in case username or/and email already exists.
2. After that, i would like to filter the submissions on my needs. For example i would like to restrict username's or password's length or filter them based on a regex. Again, how am i to do that and create a http error response with a specific message that would describe the violation that occurred?

Please, if you are going to post any code from the internet, make sure to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a query in your repository that will try to fetch a User for each parameter.

```
Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
```

Then, you can program the logic in the case username or email already exists in the database.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SignUpController {

@Autowired
UserRepo repo;

@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void signUp(@Valid @RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    Optional<User> usernameEntry = repo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    Optional<User> emailEntry = repo.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
    if(usernameEntry.isPresent()){
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Username already exists!");
    } 
    if(emailEntry.isPresent()){
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Email already exists!");
    }
    if(validateInputs(user)){ // filter as you need in this method
        repo.save(user);
        System.out.println("New user submission!");
    }
}

private boolean validateInputs(User user) throws Exception{
    // validations and exceptions as you need here
}
```

The logic for your exceptions with your filters work the same, throwing the needed exception within the method. That being said, I think it would be easier if you just set the lenght of the input directly in the front end. Also, I don't think you should limit how strong a user wants their password to be, and if you're concerned about the lenght in your storage, encryption algorithms like [BCrypt](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt) have set lenghts. For further reading about the ResponseStatusException I took for this example, you can read this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception).